# conditionalPanel() and if statements - server output not consistent: Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using these commands for the ui.R in Shiny. Now each of these methods run individually but when I try running 2 methods from the same group, say group1 methods. It does not show me outputs.

please look into the sample code or ui and server and suggest changes.

I am trying to display heatmaps and tables for this kind of data. As shown the server code repeats for method "M". In that case the methods S doesnt show any plots or tables. Sometimes occasionally, it prints out the table but not the plot. They are named similarly with some changes to the variable names.

**In short, I am able to show the outputs when a method is selected (M or S). I want it to show the outputs when both the methods are selected (M and S)**

```
# packages used
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  library(MASS)
  library(preprocessCore)
  library(DT)
  library(pheatmap)
  library(ggplot2)
#---------ui-----------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("2 groups of methods"),
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs", 
              tabPanel(id = "tab1", title = "Submit info",
                       hr(),
                       
                       fluidRow(
                         column(10,
                                wellPanel(
                                  awesomeCheckboxGroup("method",
                                                       label = ("group1 methods"),
                                                       choices = c("M1" = "M", "S1"='S'),
                                                       inline = TRUE, status = "primary"
                                  ),
                                  
                                  # if method = M or S then execute below.
                                  conditionalPanel(
                                    condition = "input.method.includes('M') || input.method.includes('S')",
                                    wellPanel(
                                      awesomeCheckboxGroup(inputId = "internal_data", "Choose our data",
                                                           c("one"="one", "two"="two")),
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
                         )
                         )
              )
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "plots",
           fluidRow(column(width = 4,
                           wellPanel(
                             plotOutput("plot"),
                             
                             DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
                      
)
)
)
)
)
                                

#---------SERVER-----------------
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    plot_method = reactiveVal()
    output_methods <- reactive({
        if(input$internal_data == "one" && input$method == "M"){
        log_info("Deconvolution with MUSIC started")
        isolate({
          x <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))
          plot_method(pheatmap(x))
        })
      }
      if(input$internal_data == "two" && input$method == "M"){
        log_info("Deconvolution with MUSIC started")
        isolate({
          x <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(100:101,300,rep=TRUE)))
          plot_method(pheatmap(x))
        })
      }
     x <- x
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      output_methods()
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot_method()
    })
    
  }
```

Comment: You forgot the code. You can edit your question.

Comment: Hi , i just edited it! apologies!

Comment: Please include the necessary `library` calls. I see you're using `DT`, `shinyWidgets`, and a package providing the `pheatmap` function.

Comment: okay edited that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you want.

If you want to show the outputs only when the method is M, do

```
  Data  <- reactive({
    req(input$internal_data, identical(input$method, "M")) 
    if(input$internal_data == "one"){
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)))
    }else{
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(100:101, 300, rep=TRUE)))
    }
  })
  output$table <- renderDT(Data())
  output$plot <- renderPlot(pheatmap(Data()))
```

If you want to show the outputs when a method is selected (M or S), do

```
  Data  <- reactive({
    req(input$internal_data, input$method) 
    if(input$internal_data == "one"){
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)))
    }else{
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(100:101, 300, rep=TRUE)))
    }
  })
```

If you want to show the outputs when at least the method M is selected, do

```
  Data  <- reactive({
    req(input$internal_data, "M" %in% input$method) 
    if(input$internal_data == "one"){
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)))
    }else{
      data.frame(replicate(10, sample(100:101, 300, rep=TRUE)))
    }
  })
```

There will be a problem if you select both `"one"` and `"two"`. I think you should use `radioButtons` instead of `awesomeCheckboxGroup`, in order to select one and only one choice.

Regarding your conditional panel, use this condition:

```
condition = "input.method !== null"
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Laurent. It works for me. I guess i was getting lost inside the bulkiness of my code. Apologies for not being concise with my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems `conditionalPanel()` doesn't like `includes()` function. You can use `indexOf()`instead:

```r
condition = "input.method.indexOf('M')>=0 || input.method.indexOf('S')>=0",
```

To avoid error in the reactive when the inputs are not selected yet, you can use`req()` to stop the job if the required input are not set :

```r
  output_methods <- reactive({
    req(input$internal_data, input$method) # Cancel the call if these inputs not sets
    ...
```

You can even specify the values that are mandatory

```r
req(input$internal_data, input$method == "M")
```

Finally, it would be simpler to compute the data first and chain the reactives this way:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  data  <- reactive({
    req(input$internal_data, input$method == "M") # Cancel the computation on invalid inputs
    # Compute and return data
    ...
  })
  output$table <- renderDataTable(data())
  output$plot <- renderPlot(pheatmap(data()))
}
```

Comment: okay, in my final code the tab is inside the tabset panel. I made an error while putting it up here. 

I tried req() as well, it still does not work
@HubertL

Comment: @HubertL, one can select both methods M and S, and `input$method` will be `c("M","S")`, and in JavaScript this will be `["M","S"]`.

Comment: I changed the condition using `indexOf()`, it seems conditinalPanel doesn't like `includes()`

Comment: Hi @HubertL, I have used conditional panel with indexOf() as well, it still works partially

Comment: Try to reorganize the code as I suggests at the end of my answer

Comment: @HubertL I tried all the suggestive edits. It still doesnt print a table or a plot randomly. I wonder if I should change something else

Comment: It's hard to help with random errors. Try to avoid side effect like updating reactiveVal inside a reactive